# Adding two strings in stl

Tags: c++, string

Is there any way to add two string without using any loop, if there is any inbuilt function?

i.e if first string is lets say, "1234" and second is "0010"  (the two will always be of the same length), can i add them to get "1244" without using loop?

Question within a question: What if the lengths are not same?

PS: length not same I mean this:
i.e. if string A; where A is of length 4 and values: '1', '12', '12', '10' ans string b; where b is "1234", then by adding i want '2', '14', '15', '14'. The resultant is also of length 4 but notice the addition, its as per the index.

Comment: Yes - why do you think a loop would be needed?

Comment: To verify – you want to add the numeric value of two strings representing decimal numbers, and store the result in a new string? Or what, precisely, do you want?

Comment: You have to convert them to a int or double and add them.

Comment: @TimCastelijns This atoi thing just slipped, and moreover with the time limit and string length i have, this may or may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 std::string s1 = "1234";
 std::string s2 = "0010";
 int s = atoi(s1.c_str()) + atoi(s2.c_str());
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << s;
 cout << ss.str() << endl;
```

Comment: What all m wondering is, will this work for string lengths upto 10^5 seconds in the prescribed time limit with other things of my code.

Comment: @user3552407 If you don't mention any requirements in your question you cannot expect people to post answers that meet those requirements

Comment: Yeah, but the comment was all general. Is there any way out to increment the string by its index.? I mean if the string is "00010", then can I make it "01244" without loop?

Comment: @TimCastelijns can u please help with the above one??

Comment: @user3552407 the solution in this answer can handle that, too

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at the code below:

```
std::string A("123"), B("321");
int res = std::stoi(A) + std::stoi(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 or later:

```
std::string result = std::to_string(std::stoi(s1) + std::stoi(s2));
```

Historically, you had to faff around with dodgy C-library functions like `strtol`, or string-streams, remembering to check the results if there's any chance that the strings might not contain numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert to two `int` -> `atoi`
2. plus them
3. convert result to `string` -> `itoa`

float, double the same .